# Route FaceTime notification sounds through internal/non-hdmi speaker

Tags: audio, notifications, facetime

I'm setting up an old Mac Mini as a home theater machine. We'll use it for, among other things, letting the kids FaceTime with Grandma on the big screen.

Here's my question. I want most audio played through the TV via the hdmi connection. But... can I set things up so FaceTime notification (when Grandma calls) and *only* the FaceTime notifications will play through the a different speaker, so we can hear when Grandma calls even if the TV is off? Or, failing that, notification sounds in general will play through the alternate speaker but application sounds play through the TV as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Sure! Although only for all sound effects, as far as I know. Just go to the Sound pane in System Preferences, and switch "Play sound effects through" to your other output device.

[image: sound-effects-output-select]